# GLFW Shared DLL can't compile

Tags: c++, c, makefile, x11, glfw

I am trying to compile GLFW to use with [pyglfw](https://bitbucket.org/pyglfw/pyglfw) in cygwin.

Compiling GLFW with normal cmake flags does not work as expected, the boing.exe example don't compile.
Here is the verbose version of the Makefile output.

```
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -H/build/glfw-latest150107 -B/build/glfw-latest150107 --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
make -f src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
cd /build/glfw-latest150107 && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /build/glfw-latest150107 /build/glfw-latest150107/src /build/glfw-latest150107 /build/glfw-latest150107/src /build/glfw-latest150107/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target glfw
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
make -f src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 13
[  2%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/clipboard.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/clipboard.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/clipboard.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 14
[  4%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/context.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 15
[  6%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/gamma.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/gamma.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/gamma.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 16
[  8%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/init.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 17
[ 10%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/input.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 18
[ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/joystick.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/joystick.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/joystick.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 19
[ 14%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/monitor.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 20
[ 16%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/time.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/time.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/time.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 21
[ 18%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/window.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 22
[ 20%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_clipboard.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_clipboard.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_clipboard.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 23
[ 22%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_gamma.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_gamma.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_gamma.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 24
[ 24%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_init.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_init.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_init.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 25
[ 26%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_joystick.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_joystick.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_joystick.c
/build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_joystick.c:47:12: warning: ‘openJoystickDevice’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int openJoystickDevice(int joy, const char* path)
            ^
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 26
[ 28%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_monitor.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_monitor.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_monitor.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 27
[ 30%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_time.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_time.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_time.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 28
[ 32%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_window.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_window.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_window.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 29
[ 34%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_unicode.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_unicode.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_unicode.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 30
[ 36%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/glx_context.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/glx_context.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/glx_context.c
Linking C static library libglfw3.a
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -P CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar.exe cr libglfw3.a  CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/clipboard.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/gamma.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/joystick.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/time.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_clipboard.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_gamma.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_init.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_joystick.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_monitor.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_time.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_window.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_unicode.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/glx_context.c.o
/usr/bin/ranlib.exe libglfw3.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles  13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
[ 36%] Built target glfw
make -f examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/build.make examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
cd /build/glfw-latest150107 && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /build/glfw-latest150107 /build/glfw-latest150107/examples /build/glfw-latest150107 /build/glfw-latest150107/examples /build/glfw-latest150107/examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target boing
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
make -f examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/build.make examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 2
[ 38%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/boing.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/examples && /usr/bin/cc   -I/build/glfw-latest150107/include -I/build/glfw-latest150107/deps    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/boing.dir/boing.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/examples/boing.c
Linking C executable boing.exe
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/examples && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/boing.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc    -Wl,--enable-auto-import  -mwindows CMakeFiles/boing.dir/boing.c.o  -o boing.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libboing.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  ../src/libglfw3.a /usr/local/lib/libGLU.dll.a -lX11 -Wl,-Bstatic -lrt -Wl,-Bdynamic -lXrandr -lXi /usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lrt -lm -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL -lXrandr -lXi /usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lm -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `find_display':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75: undefined reference to `XextFindDisplay'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75:(.text+0x18): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XextFindDisplay'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75: undefined reference to `XextCreateExtension'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75:(.text+0x31): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XextCreateExtension'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75: undefined reference to `XextAddDisplay'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75:(.text+0x7a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XextAddDisplay'
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `XF86VidModeSetClientVersion':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:139: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:139:(.text+0x11d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:136: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:136:(.text+0x181): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XMissingExtension'
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `XF86VidModeQueryVersion':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:113: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:113:(.text+0x1da): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:116: undefined reference to `_XReply'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:116:(.text+0x1fa): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_XReply'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:110: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:110:(.text+0x28e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XMissingExtension'
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `XF86VidModeSetGamma':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:158: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:158:(.text+0x2ec): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:155: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:155:(.text+0x38d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XMissingExtension'
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `XF86VidModeGetGamma':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:180: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:180:(.text+0x3ec): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:184: undefined reference to `_XReply'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:177: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `XF86VidModeGetModeLine':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:211: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:236: undefined reference to `_XReply'
####
# Ommited some lines, you get the basic idea
####
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `close_display':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:80: undefined reference to `XextRemoveDisplay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/build.make:106: recipe for target 'examples/boing.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [examples/boing.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:172: recipe for target 'examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/boing.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
Makefile:119: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And to use glfw with pyglfw I have to use the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1` option in ccmake.

I have compiled and installed libXxf86vm from source, but what bothers me is that the src I built from is called(?) for these functions, shouldn't it use the .dll files in `/usr/local/lib/`

```
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `close_display':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:80: undefined reference to `XextRemoveDisplay'
```

To actually install libXxf86vm I had to compile and install `xf86vidmodeproto`, but that is working for me now(I think).

Now the Makefile output with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1`.

```
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -H/build/glfw-latest150107 -B/build/glfw-latest150107 --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
make -f src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
cd /build/glfw-latest150107 && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /build/glfw-latest150107 /build/glfw-latest150107/src /build/glfw-latest150107 /build/glfw-latest150107/src /build/glfw-latest150107/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target glfw
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
make -f src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 13
[  2%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/clipboard.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/clipboard.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/clipboard.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 14
[  4%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/context.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 15
[  6%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/gamma.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/gamma.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/gamma.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 16
[  8%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/init.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 17
[ 10%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/input.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 18
[ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/joystick.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/joystick.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/joystick.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 19
[ 14%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/monitor.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 20
[ 16%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/time.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/time.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/time.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 21
[ 18%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/window.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 22
[ 20%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_clipboard.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_clipboard.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_clipboard.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 23
[ 22%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_gamma.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_gamma.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_gamma.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 24
[ 24%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_init.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_init.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_init.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 25
[ 26%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_joystick.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_joystick.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_joystick.c
/build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_joystick.c:47:12: warning: ‘openJoystickDevice’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int openJoystickDevice(int joy, const char* path)
            ^
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 26
[ 28%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_monitor.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_monitor.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_monitor.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 27
[ 30%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_time.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_time.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_time.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 28
[ 32%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_window.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_window.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_window.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 29
[ 34%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_unicode.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_unicode.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/x11_unicode.c
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /build/glfw-latest150107/CMakeFiles 30
[ 36%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/glx_context.c.o
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cc  -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H -Dglfw_EXPORTS -I/build/glfw-latest150107/src -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/glx_context.c.o   -c /build/glfw-latest150107/src/glx_context.c
Linking C shared library cygglfw-3.dll
cd /build/glfw-latest150107/src && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc      -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-import -o cygglfw-3.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libglfw.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,3,--minor-image-version,0 CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/clipboard.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/gamma.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/joystick.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/time.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_clipboard.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_gamma.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_init.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_joystick.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_monitor.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_time.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_window.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_unicode.c.o CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/glx_context.c.o -lX11 -Wl,-Bstatic -lrt -Wl,-Bdynamic -lXrandr -lXi /usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lrt -lm -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL -lXrandr -lXi /usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lm -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `find_display':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75: undefined reference to `XextFindDisplay'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75:(.text+0x18): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XextFindDisplay'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75: undefined reference to `XextCreateExtension'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75:(.text+0x31): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XextCreateExtension'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75: undefined reference to `XextAddDisplay'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:75:(.text+0x7a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XextAddDisplay'
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `XF86VidModeSetClientVersion':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:139: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:139:(.text+0x11d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:136: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:136:(.text+0x181): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XMissingExtension'
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `XF86VidModeQueryVersion':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:113: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:113:(.text+0x1da): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:116: undefined reference to `_XReply'
####
# Ommited some lines, you get the basic idea
####
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `XF86VidModeGetPermissions':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:1170: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:1174: undefined reference to `_XReply'
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:1167: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/usr/local/lib/libXxf86vm.a(XF86VMode.o): In function `close_display':
/build/libXxf86vm-1.1.2/src/XF86VMode.c:80: undefined reference to `XextRemoveDisplay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build.make:529: recipe for target 'src/cygglfw-3.dll' failed
make[2]: *** [src/cygglfw-3.dll] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:112: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build/glfw-latest150107'
Makefile:119: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix this problem so that I can build the shared libs?

Comment: It sometimes isn't enough just to list all the dependencies and feed them to linker.
Order matters to linker. This is what I've got:  `${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} Xxf86vm Xrandr Xi Xext glfw pthread ${X11_LIBRARIES}`

Comment: Anyway, you are compiling GLFW under windows, why don't you just use the windows version without X11?

Comment: I'm using cygwin, that's why I have to use X11(?). I also want to be using this on as many platforms as I can.

Also, where did you get those variables? I can't seem to find them.

Comment: glfw is a cross-platform library, so if you want to make a glfw program for multiple platforms, the only thing you have to do is to use cmake, it will do most of work for you. Those variables can be obtained using `find_library` in cmake, but they can be easily replaced with GL for the first one, and x11 for the second one.

Comment: You are compiling GLFW for X11. Since you are using Windows, you should [compile it for Windows](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile.html#compile_deps_mingw_cross).

Comment: I did that and cmake recognizes that manually specified CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE isn't used by project. CMake is version 2.8.11.2, so that variable should be recognized.

Comment: I just defined `CMAKE_LEGACY_WIN32` to True and see and behold, it is now set to win32 for window- and WGL for context- creation.
I am now getting errors with `__imp_wglgetProcAddress` and more, but I think I haven't set the wgl library, will see if I can fix.